# how to avoid hard coding login credentials in yaml for gpload

Tags: postgresql, security, yaml, greenplum

I have a problem I cannot get around. I am using YAML for loading a CSV to a gpdb table. I want to avoid hard coding the database login details (host, id, password). YAML does not support include or import option. How can I concatenate or call the credentials stored in a second file to the right place in the YAML script used for execution?

```
--- 
VERSION:
DATABASE: dbname        # <- these should be dynamic
USER: user              # <-
PASSWORD: itsasecret    # <-
HOST: server_address    # <-
PORT: 1234              # <-
GPLOAD:
  input...
  output...
```

Comment: I am not sure why you put `**` before `DATABASE`, that makes your YAML file invalid as `*` should introduce an alias and an alias cannot start with a `*`.

Comment: Anthon, thanks for your comment. I was trying to make that part as a bold or italic to highlight it. For some reason it does not show that way :-|

Comment: You cannot bold something in an indented code segment, that is all "literal" . But you can put comments in YAML to point out what needs emphasis.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. Do you have any suggestions how I can make those specific columns dynamic/encrypted?

Comment: What I did for dockercompose, that has environments variable substitution in its YAML file, but lacks being able to set defaults is wrap the original command in a python program, that does extract the defaults writes a new YAML file and then call the original program. If that (ie. running a wrapper program in python) would be an option I can write that as an answer (with working code).

Answer (score 1):

You can call gpload with command line arguments to specify the host and user and get them out of the YAML file itself:

```
gpload -f yourfile.yml -h database_server_name -U user_login_name
```

You can set the password as:

`$PGPASSWORD` environment variable with password in it
`$PGPASSFILE` environment variable pointing to a file with the password for that user
put the login information in `.pgpass`

You can add a `-W` to the command line to force a password prompt if you don't want to store it in a file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jim! I forgot about pgpass. I am using gpload with an ETL tool, not through the psql. This is being operated by a DBA who will not use my functional ID for deployed the job. Is there a way to incorporate that into the yaml file? I have read that PyYaml has a way using !include x.yaml, it seems more tedious to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to include things in the YAML files we use.  You should be able to embed the user and host in the YAML file.  If that user is validated on the system via pg_hba.conf  and there is an entry for your user in .pgpass, this should get you in.   Generally speaking ETL tools like Informatica or AbInitio that use gpload will have a specific ETL role set up in the database and pg_hba.conf for all ETL jobs to login as.   Most of the customers I deal with use that very model.